# Google Charts not working in Materialize accordion

Tags: angular, charts, google-visualization, materialize

I am trying to draw the google line charts in accordion in a project built with Angular2 & Materializecss. I am aware that google chart don't take full width if drawn in hidden section of DOM. So to apply full width to charts, I tried opening the accordion just before calling the draw method along with data and options. Here in below snapshot of line chart I am getting with no X-Y axis and even legends for the lines in not showing up correctly. 
Snapshot of chart if drawn in accordion.
[image]

with same data and options but without accordion gives below result.

[image]

Can anyone tell me what can be the reason for this issue? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: options used are as follow:
let options = {
tooltip: { isHtml: true },
curveType: 'function',
lineWidth: 5,
legend: 'none',
seriesType: "line",
series: {1: {type: "line", color: '#9966ff', visibleInLegend: false, areaOpacity: 0, enableInteractivity: false}, 2: {type: "line", color: '#660066', visibleInLegend: false, areaOpacity: 0, enableInteractivity: false}},
explorer: {},
width: '100%',
height: '100%',
chartArea: {
left: "15%",
top: "3%",
height: "80%",
width: "100%"
},
hAxis : { 
textStyle : {
fontSize: 9
}
 }
 };

Answer (score 2):

You can trigger the drawing when `onOpen` is called:

http://materializecss.com/collapsible.html#options

You can get the opened element with the first parameter of it.

```
  $('.collapsible').collapsible({
    accordion: false, // A setting that changes the collapsible behavior to expandable instead of the default accordion style
    onOpen: function(el) { alert('Open'); }, // Callback for Collapsible open
    onClose: function(el) { alert('Closed'); } // Callback for Collapsible close
  });
```